# Upload image error in wordpress custom templete

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I am trying to code for upload image in custom word-press template. It is working in php. When i move it on word-press template, it shows warning and stop executing the script. Here is my code. Assume all the table and folder are created with proper permission 777.

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-load.php');
require('../../../wp-config.php');
function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
   if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
   switch($imagetype)
   {
       case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
       case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
       case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
       case 'image/png': return '.png';
       default: return false;
   }
 }

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=bloginfo('template_directory').$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];

    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;

    $tmp=bloginfo('template_directory');
    $remain = "/images/".$imagename;
    $target_path = $tmp.$remain;

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

        $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path) VALUES ('$target_path')";
        mysql_query($query_upload) or die(mysql_error());  
    }else{
       exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 
}
```

?>

Output:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/16-12-2014-1418709361.gif) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress2/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/saveimage.php on line 31

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpuS9XNY' to '/images/16-12-2014-1418709361.gif' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress2/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/saveimage.php on line 31
Error While uploading image on the server
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please you try this 
One more thing  you remember when we  move file need 2 parameter 
    a file name 
    b path of the folder which one you want move your picture.
ex :  $destination = "test/". $name;// this is  path

$answer = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'],$destination);
```

Comment: Error While uploading image on the server

Comment: Please you check your upload folder have full access permission.

Comment: I think your above code wrong so please you refer this link
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-custom-upload-folder